# ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: delphi, excel, excel-2007, c++builder, ole

Why the following code return invalid parameter error? Its equivalent in Delphi executes well.

C++ Builder:

```
ActiveWorkSheet.OleProcedure("ExportAsFixedFormat", 0, EmptyParam,
        EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
        EmptyParam);
```

Delphi:

```
  oSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, // xlTypePDF is constant 0
    EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
    EmptyParam, // set to True to open Acrobat
    EmptyParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another EmptyParam. The function has 9 parameters so when you call it using OleProcedure you mush send 10 parameters (since the first parameter is the function name). You're only sending 9.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (at least in VC) the parameter order have to be reversed. Try this:

ActiveWorkSheet.OleProcedure("ExportAsFixedFormat", EmptyParam,
        EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
        EmptyParam, 0);

Hope this would help